# How to fix UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-studio, security

Following my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // my code
    }
}
```

And it is registered in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The linter reports the following error in the onReceive method of MyBroadcastReceiver:

> This broadcast receiver declares an intent-filter for a protected
>   broadcast action string, which can only be sent by the system, not
>   third-party applications. However, the receiver's onReceive method
>   does not appear to call getAction to ensure that the received Intent's
>   action string matches the expected value, potentially making it
>   possible for another actor to send a spoofed intent with no action
>   string or a different action string and cause undesired behavior.
>   BroadcastReceivers that declare an intent-filter for a
>   protected-broadcast action string must check that the received
>   intent's action string matches the expected value, otherwise it is
>   possible for malicious actors to spoof intents.
>
> Issue id: UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver

How to fix UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Filter the action, like it says to do:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED:
                //what you want to do
                break;
            case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                //what you want to do
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't check that, any app can "call" BOOT_COMPLETED on your Receiver simply by specifying the classname, since that bypasses the filter.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work. Just another question, how to check if  intent.getAction() is android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON? Intent.ACTION_QUICKBOOT_POWERON does not exist...

Comment: Just put it as a constant.

Comment: Something like intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON")?

Comment: No, just add the string as a new case in the switch statement.

Comment: I understand, but is the string you're talking about: "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"?

Comment: Yes. That's what I'm talking about. Do you not know how to use switch statements? I can replace it in my answer with an if-else block if not.

Comment: Perfect! I know how to use switch statements, but I'm using a single if because the code to execute in case of Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED and Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED is the same. Thank you again!